# Passing strings to Django URL in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

I think this is probably something very simple, but I can't figure out for the life of me why these urls aren't matching.

My template code looks like this:

```
<form action="{% url 'view_record' "facility_report" %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}

{{ form }}

<input type="submit" value="View Report" name='view' label="Submit">  </form>
```

The url is then supposed to match this line in my url conf:

```
url(r'^view_record/((?P<report_type>.+)/)?$', views.view_record, name='view_record'),
```

What am I missing here? They simply won't match and most of the other questions regarding this are from five years ago when the engine seems to have been a lot more picky with formatting.

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /view_record/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'view_record' with arguments '('facility_report',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['view_record/((?P<report_type>(.*))/)?$']
```

Comment: can you show your views.py file?

Comment: What does the traceback say?

Comment: It's a reverse url matching error, couldn't match '('facility_record',)' after trying the posted url. I'll put up the exact log and view momentarily.

Comment: Ok, added the error message. The view is actually quite large and is unrelated to the error as far as I know.

Comment: can you tell what arguements are you passing in views?

Comment: I pass `request` and `report_type` to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer group in `((?P<report_type>.+)/)?` is a capturing group. Django's url reversal can't handle nested capturing groups, so it will only catch the outer group as a possible argument. Since the first argument does not end in a `/`, the pattern doesn't match and a `NoReverseMatch` is thrown.

You can change the outer group to a non-capturing group, and Django will pick up the inner group as a capturing group. That way, the argument does not have to contain the `/`, as only the inner group is replaced, and the outer group is used as-is.

To create a non-capturing group, start the group with `?:`:

```
url(r'^view_record/(?:(?P<report_type>.+)/)?$', views.view_record, name='view_record'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<form action="{%url 'view_record' 'facility_report'%}" method="post">
```

And in your `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^view_record/(?P<report_type>(.*))/$', views.view_record, name='view_record')
```

This should send the form to the correct url.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid hard coding the url if possible.

Comment: Updated the answer. The problem was probably due to quotes. Hopefully this should solve your problem.

Comment: It keeps giving me the same error as before. This appears to be the correct format though, I'm really stumped as to why it isn't matching.